# Move an object in unity2D towards another clicked object

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, unity3d-2dtools

- I have an object called '*Player*' in my scene.
- I also have multiple objects called '*Trees*'.

Now I'd like whenever the user clicks on a 'Tree', the 'Player' to move slowly to that position (using Lerp or moveTowards) is both O.K for me.

---

Now I have 2 issues with this code:

#### I'd like this code to be generic

Whenever I click a *tree object* I'd like this to move the *player* towards that *tree*. I don't want to write up this script and attach it to each *tree object*.

- Where should I put the script?

  Currently I attach this code to every *tree object*.
- How should I write it down so that it applies to every *tree object*
  in the scene?

#### If another click is made while moving, cancel previous movement and start moving to new position

- How should I write it so that if I click on another object while the
  *player* is moving towards another object that was clicked, the players stops moving towards it's previous position, and starts
  moving towards the new point.

I'm having some trouble adjusting to the new UnityScript thingy. I come strictly from a Javascript background and it really seems like the 2 of them are languages with very different semantics. So if someone answers this with code(which is what I would want:) ), I'd appreciate some verbose comments as well.

---

I currently do this:

```
var playerIsMoving = false;
Public playerObject: Gameobject; //I drag in the editor the player in this public var

function update(){  

   var thisTreePosition = transform.point; //this store the X pos of the tree
   var playerPosition = player.transform.point;

   if(playerIsMoving){
    player.transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(playerPosition, thisTreePosition, step);
   }

}

function OnMouseDown(){
    playerIsMoving = true;
}
```

*I'm writing this from home where I don't have Unity and I forgot the code syntax therefore expect the above code to have typos or issues, at work it works just fine, apart from being very crude and unsophisticated*.

Comment: Is there a reason why you've got the trees responsible for the movement of the player, and not the player GameObject itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I've done it myself (with *some* help from Freshchris's answer).

Here it is:

```
var target:Vector2;
var targetObject:GameObject;
var initialY:float;
var tolerance = 1;
var speed = 3;
var isMoving = false;

function Start(){
    target = transform.position; 
}

function Update () {

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
        var hit: RaycastHit2D = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), Vector2.zero); //raycast the scene

        // if we hit something
        if (hit.collider != null) {
            isMoving=true; //it should start moving
            targetObject = hit.collider.gameObject; //the target object 
            target = hit.collider.gameObject.transform.position;
        }
    }

    // The step size is equal to speed times frame time.
    var step = speed * Time.deltaTime;

    // if it should be moving - move it - and face the player to the correct direction
    if (isMoving){
        if(transform.position.x>target.x){
            gameObject.transform.localScale.x =  -0.7;
        }else {
            gameObject.transform.localScale.x =  0.7;
        }
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, target, step);
    }

    // if it reached the target object by a specified tolerance, tell it to stop moving
    if(isMoving){
        if((transform.position.x < target.x+tolerance)&&(transform.position.x > target.x-tolerance)){
            print("position reached"); //this is fired just once since isMoving is switched to false just one line below
            print(targetObject);
            isMoving=false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you to put the movement Script on the player. And how abour using Raycast to the test whether you hit a tree?

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html

```
Vector3 positionToWalkTo = new Vector3();

void Update() {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            RaycastHit hit;
            Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, direction);

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
               if (hit.gameObject.tag.Equals("tree")){
                  positionToWalkTo = hit.gameObject.transform.position;
               }

        }

        float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, positionToWalkTo, step);
    }
```

To get something like this running, you should tag all the trees.

'JavaScript'

```
var target: Transform;
// Speed in units per sec.
var speed: float;

function Update () {

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
             var hit: RaycastHit;
             var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);

        // Raycasting is like shooting something into the given direction (ray) and hit is the object which got hit
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, hit)) {
            if (hit.gameObject.tag = "tree")
                target = hit.gameObject.transform.position;  // Sets the new target position
        }
    }

    // The step size is equal to speed times frame time.
    var step = speed * Time.deltaTime;

    // Move our position a step closer to the target.
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, step);
}
```

Comment: thanks, if you have the time and knowledge, is it possible to write this in JavaScript and put some comments as well? I'd like to understand it as best as possible since I would be using this a lot

Comment: Yeah i try, give me a sec

Comment: 3 questions I'd like to ask - 1st question - where is speed declared? I understand Time.deltaTime must be a preset method of unity that returns ms in terms of time per frame - but where was speed value declared? - 2nd question - Since the *transform position* part of the code is outside the IF , wouldn't the console throw errors since the targetPosition is undefined until I click something? I'll accept this answer now and ask something outside of the scope of this question. - 3rd question -  How do I know if the player has reached his intended position?

Comment: Speed added in code, you just have to assign a value. To the second thing , you could surround the transform.position = .... line with an `if(target != null)`. To test whether the player has reached the goal `if(transform.position == target.position){//target reached}`

Comment: and on the 3rd point - I could just say `if(transform.point === target.position) { //do something here }`, right?

Comment: ok now it gives me the variable target of playerScript has not been assigned.